# Cell shading not shown when table rows break over pages

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2013, microsoft-office-2013

I have a table with several cells in the left columns merged to span large amounts of the table. This is to colour-code the cells the the right of them - different parts of the table are grouped together with colours.

I'm applying cell shading with a colour, and this works fine until the cell ends up splitting over multiple pages. On the second one it displays okay, but by the third page the columns sometimes stop showing colour. When I export to PDF, none of the columns have any shading past the first page.

[image]
- note the missing red column where the arrow is pointing.

I'm not sure the exact cause of this, it seems to come and go as I add and remove text, but in any case it never displays colour past the first page when I export to PDF. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I found that the easiest solution is to just re-split the left coloured cells after formatting them. The Split Cell dialogue only lets you break them into an appropriate number of cells to match the rest of the table (or multiples of it), so it doesn't mess the formatting up.